# Long pause 4-5 seconds after clicking in certain Word 2010 Documents

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I have a subset of documents that create a pause of 4-5 seconds everytime I focus on the Microsoft Word window containing it.

The documents are created using a .dotx file, but seperately created documents created from the .dotx file.

I'm using Microsoft Word 2010, version 14.0.7162.5000.

I'm assuming Word is looking for something that it can't find anymore. I've deleted normal.dot but this did not improve the situation. I've removed the check in the box 'automatically refresh links when opening the document'.

I've looked into forums and the Microsoft knowledge base and was not successfull.

Right now I'd like to be able to see some sort of low-level log that tell me what Word is trying to do, because it's driving me crazy to wait 4-5 seconds every time I blur out of the window and refocus in it.

Any help or tips greatly appreciated.

**update**
opening word in safe mode removes the delays, now the question becomes 'which plug-in is borking my installation', or how should I reinstall the plug-ins?

**second update**
problem persists when the document is copied (i.e. when I work on a copied version).
problem persists when everything is deleted (CTRL-A, Delete).
problem persist with every document made from that template (.docx)

Active Add-ins:
Duden-Rechtschreibprüfung, COM Add-In adxloader.dll
Instant Messaging-Kontakte (Deutsch)IMCONTACT.DLL
Measurement Converter (Measurement Converter) METCONV.DLL

Comment: Does the problem persist if you copy one of them? What happens if you then completely clear the contents(Ctrl+A, DEL)? Does this happen for all documents created with your .dotx file?

Comment: sorry for the late answer BramMooij, I've updated the question. Looks like I should rebuild the .dotx file from scratch with new then ctrl-a-copy-paste. Or is there a better way?